# How To Configure Multiple Virtual Machines As An Internal Network Via SSH

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ssh

First of all, I am using Windows 7 as a host. Then I install Ubuntu 12.04 Guest under VirtualBox.

Then I get an access to the other four virtual machines (also Ubuntu 12.04 Guest) via ssh by running the following command in my Ubuntu Guest' terminal:

```
ssh user@ipaddress
```

Then I want to connect those four virtual machines in an Internal Network, is there any ways to connect them under my Ubuntu Guest? 
I'm confused since I can only access those four virtual machines via ssh on my Ubuntu's terminal.

EDIT:

What I mean by "connect" is to physically connect them using their ethernet. For example, VM1 connect to VM2 by using eth1 on VM1 and eth2 on VM2.
I can do this in virtualbox, just add network adapter "Internal Network" for both of them.
But as I said, I can only access those VMs via my Ubuntu's terminal, I don't have any access on their virtualbox.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you,

Dulipat

Comment: To get an answer you may need to further specify what you exactly mean by *"connect"* - they are already clients, i.e. connected in your virtual network. You would not be able to SSH otherwise.

Comment: In the settings of your VM guests, there is a tab "Network" with various options. Which ones have you tried? I think you should set the connection method to "Internal network".